# SwiftUI - Combine: Binding Subject in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

In my viewModel I have either a `CurrentValueSubject` or a `PassthroughSubject`.

How can I bind them in my **SwiftU** where the view is expecting an input of type `@Binding<Type>`.

I've tried with but it doesn't work properly:

```
extension CurrentValueSubject {
  var binding: Binding<Output> {
    Binding(get: {
      self.value
    }, set: {
      self.send($0)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use .onReceive modifier like below:

```
// View Model
class MyVM {
    var sub: CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>
}
 
// View
struct MyView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi..")
        .onReceive(viewModel.sub) { newValue in
            // Here create binding or assign it to @State variable
        }
    }
}
```